# Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 7

Tags: find, file-get-contents

I have the following error with this code, I want it to grab a chosen object from the HTML, not the entire file.

**php file:**

```
<?php 
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$target = "test.html";
$html = file_get_contents($target);

foreach($html->find('div.article') as $element) 
       echo $element->find('h1');

?>
```

**test.html:**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="article">
<h1>Header</h1>
<p>Paragraph</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 7
```

Answer (score 0):

file_get_contents() returns a string object.

A string object dont have find method. Refer http://php.net/manual/en/book.strings.php.

use this instead

file_get_html()

```
<?php 
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$target = "test.html";
$html = file_get_html($target);

foreach($html->find('div.article') as $element) 
       echo $element->find('h1');

?>
```